# How to upgrade helm from 2 to 3 version in jenkinsx installed in okd environment

Tags: kubernetes-helm, jenkins-x

I want to upgrade helm version from 2 version to 3 version since I am facing "Could not find tiller" issue in while using "helm delete --purge " in JenkinsX.

So upgrade does not depend on tiller and makes my job easy. Please help me to resolve this.

```
jx step helm build
WARNING: No $CHART_REPOSITORY defined so using the default value of: http://jenkins-x-chartmuseum:8080
Adding missing Helm repo: storage.googleapis.com https://storage.googleapis.com/chartmuseum.jenkins-x.io
Successfully added Helm repository storage.googleapis.com.
Adding missing Helm repo: jenkins-x-chartmuseum http://jenkins-x-chartmuseum:8080
Successfully added Helm repository jenkins-x-chartmuseum.
WARNING: No $CHART_REPOSITORY defined so using the default value of: http://jenkins-x-chartmuseum:8080
Adding missing Helm repo: chartmuseum.jenkins-x.io http://chartmuseum.jenkins-x.io
Successfully added Helm repository chartmuseum.jenkins-x.io.
EXITCODE   0[Pipeline] sh
[preview] Running shell script
+ make delete
helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: could not find tiller
```

Answer (score 0):

use the command `choco upgrade kubernetes-helm`
first install chococo/brew then use above for choco cmd or `brew upgrade helm`.

The latest Helm 3 won't need tiller pod.

Comment: Just came to know that jenkinsx is not supporting helm3 so any ideas on resolving the tiller issue in helm 2.9.0 version